# Filter/Search table in merged row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to search on the content of table. The below code is working for Filter on the rows without rowspan. But if I search content of merged row then I am not getting the expected output.

```
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/rxeLh8c9/1/)

Search on keyword "Island Trading" is working but search for "Berglunds snabbkop" is giving incorrect output.

Any help on this will be really helpful.

Comment: The JsFiddle link is not related to the question

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do. This code seems to search in the first column of each row and hide the row if `filter` is not found. What exactly do you mean by *merged row*? Do you want to search the whole row for the search term?

Comment: I have updated the link of jsfiddle.. My mistake for wrong link.

Comment: @jrook Yes! trying to filter the table which has merged rows. shared the correct fiddle link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a hidden `<td>` where there is a rowspan:

```
<tr>
    <td style="display:none;">Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
</tr>
```

And the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0j3defzs/2/

The reason this is happening is that the function is searching in the first column of the table, but spanning rows makes some rows display beside the previous row (instead of below). Inserting empty `td`s ensures the filtering function will never search in the wrong column.

**EDIT**:

I believe it makes more sense if the table had actually two columns for every row, but if we didn't want to change the table at all, something like this could  also work (fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m6cbzrh9/1/)

```
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    var show = true;
    var spannedRows = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
        if(spannedRows > 0) {
            if(show)
                tr[i].style.display = "";
            else
                tr[i].style.display = "none";
            spannedRows--;
        } else if (td) {
            if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                tr[i].style.display = "";
            } else {
                tr[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            let rs = td.getAttribute("rowspan");
            console.log("rs = " + rs);
            if(rs && rs > 1) {
                show = td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1;
                spannedRows = rs - 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is assuming that the rowspan is always defined in the first cell of a multi-row column, then filters all those rows in or out based on the result of that first cell.

Comment: Is it possible to display both country name if i search for "Alfreds Futterkiste"?

Comment: [Yes](https://jsfiddle.net/0j3defzs/2/). Just copy the data from the previous row into the hidden `td`.

Comment: My table is created dynamically through ng-repeat function of angularjs. Is it possible to achieve the same output through jquery without making any change in table

Comment: @user4324324: See edit for javascript solution, here is the updated fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/m6cbzrh9/1/